# Boolean in Mutator Method

Tags: java, boolean, mutators

I have a project in which I'm working on a class that has mutator and accessor methods. **For my mutator methods, I have to return a boolean. "True - indicating the height is within range and that the Object's value has been modified." False, obviously, if it isn't. Height being in range means it's between 1-10 inclusive.**

I know how to write a boolean, but how would I do that inside a mutator method? *Usually*, and keep in mind I'm very new, I would write something along the following:

```
public void setHeight(int newHeight){
    height = newHeight;
}
```

How would I place my boolean inside of the mutator method, as well as ensure that the height is within its proper range?
My boolean would be something along the lines of:

```
if (height >= 1 && height <= 10) {
    System.out.println("It's perfect!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not right!");
}
```

Comment: `if (height >= 1 && height >= 10)` are you sure one of those shouldn't be `<=` ?

Comment: @John3136 I changed it. Thank you for that! Obvious error is now obvious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to change the return type of your setter:

```
public boolean setHeight(int newHeight) {
    if (1<=height && height<=10) {
        height = newHeight;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than what I was doing. So whenever I want to have a boolean inside of a mutator method, I write "public bool" or "public boolean" and then have the usual mutator method?

Comment: Yup. Thanks for spotting the bool -> boolean error.

Comment: Hey, how would you do this for a tester class? I've been struggling for the past hour. I have to use the boolean value for the mutator method. So for something like myWhatever.setHeight..... what? Do you have any recommendations or links?

Comment: You don't even need the else statement, you could just have `return false` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an if statement that checks if the height is valid:

```
public boolean setHeight(int height){

    if(1 <= height && 10 >= height){

        this.height = height;
        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
```

No else statement is needed because the method ends when `return true;` is run, and thus anything after the if will not be executed if height is valid.

`this.height` refers to the `height` variable of the Object, whereas `height` in this case refers to the variable defined by the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean setHeight(int newHeight){
  if (height >= 10) {
    height = newHeight;
    System.out.println("It's perfect!");
    return true;
  }
System.out.println("Not right!");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried looking in the books and everything, but I couldn't find what I needed: the public boolean setHeight